# Importing JSON from URL in symfony2

Tags: json, symfony, twig

What is the best practice of importing json contents from a URL in Symfony2 and output the variable in twig template?

```
$url = https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `file_get_contents` to retrieve the json contents, and then pass it to the view. Your controller may look like :

```
//…
class FooController extends Controller
{
    //…
    public function getJsonContentAction()
    {
        $jsonContent = file_get_contents("https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker");

        return $this->render(
            'AppBundle:Foo:bar.html.twig', // Edit it to insert the view you want to render
            [
                'ticker' => json_decode($jsonContent),
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

And then in your twig template, display it with :

```
{{ ticker.ticker.high }}
```